# [WebStorm]: Change Debugging WebServer Project Root

Tags: webstorm

Since recently, I've been using JetBrains WebStorm and I absolutely love it, but I do have an issue, and after hours of searching here and in the documentation, I decided to open my own question because I just don't find it.

I do have a project which is stored on my Local Machine on the following location: `C:\Projects\Github\OfficeUI.Beta`

Now, I've opened up this folder in WebStorm, which causes it to looks like the following:

[image]

When I debug the WebSite right now, everything is running under the following Uri: `http://localhost:63342/OfficeUI.Beta/`

And there is the issue with it, because it's running in this Directory, in every CSS, JavaScript and other files, I need to place the following: `/OfficeUI.Beta/Resources/...`, while I would like to use: `/Resources/...`

How should this be done? I guess I need to modify WebStorm configuration to run the website under the root `http://localhost/` but I don't manage to find it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) the URL has to be `http://localhost:<built-in server port>/<project root>`. There is however a [workaround](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/03/built-in-server-in-webstorm-6/):

**Edit your /etc/hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1 projectName
```

And set custom port: `Settings -> Debugger -> JavaScript -> Built-in server port 8090`.
In newer version it should be: `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger`

The URL will be: `http://projectName:8090`

Another workaround would be to use the [PHP built-in server](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/php-built-in-web-server.html), where it's possible to define the document root. But this doesn't offer Javascript debugging.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I don't find the Settings -> Debugger - JavaScript section anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger` or simply type `port` in the search field.

Comment: If I debug the application then, the root url is the following: http://localhost:8090/OfficeUI.Beta/index.html So there's still OfficeUI.Beta in it where this should not be.

Comment: Have you edited your hosts file according to the workaround I provided?

Comment: I did, but running it seems to keep the OfficeUI.Beta path :s

Comment: **In addition to the above** you still have to *configure the Deployment entry and mark it as Default for this project*. The URL you define there will now be used instead default built-in server (it could be your own server (e.g. Apache/IIS/etc) .. or still built-in one but with `http://project-name:port/index.html` kind of simplified URL)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The project is indeed accessible under http://project-name/port/index.html' however, when I start the browser, it opens under http://localhost:port/project/index.html Is there a way to change this default behaviour so that I don't have to modify everytime I open the url?

Comment: It really sucks that there is no way to change the default behavior in the UI for this.  I guess it's so you can debug multiple projects simultaneously but I'd rather use a different port.

Answer (score 1):

As Darek Kay already suggested, the only "workaround" I'm aware of in order to use WebStorm's Built-in Server with absolute URLs is to edit your /etc/hosts file (on Mac/Linux) or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file (on Windows). In your case, you would change the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `127.0.0.1 OfficeUI.Beta`. Then, you would set a custom port for the Built-in Server by going to `Settings -> Debugger -> JavaScript -> Built-in server port 8090` (on older versions of WebStorm) or by going to `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Built-in server port 8090` (on newer versions of WebStorm). Once you've done this, you should be able to go to `http://OfficeUI.Beta:8090` and absolute URLs should work.

I would opt in for a local web server setup (Apache, MAMP, WAMP, etc) to host your web project since WebStorm's Built-in Server is very basic and doesn't address this use case.

I got this information by visiting http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/03/built-in-server-in-webstorm-6/ and looking at the comment by Vladimir Krivosheev on July 2, 2013 at 6:52 am.